# Languages used in 'Embrace of the Serpent'

Tags: dialogue, embrace-of-the-serpent

What are all the languages used in the film 'Embrace of the Serpent'?

The [NYTimes](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/02/17/movies/review-embrace-of-the-serpent-where-majesty-meets-monstrosity.html) review says there are nine but doesn't mention all of them.

I recognized German, Spanish and Latin. I would add Portuguese but Imdb says it's Catalan.
Does Karamakate speak the same native language throughout the film or does he use more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other languages are all different indigenous languages. There are many throughout the film, some that the main characters understand, and others that they do not know. **Ocaina** is spoken the most, and there is also some **Ticuna, Bora, Andoque, Yucuna (Jukuna), and Muinane**, according to the actor who plays the older Karamakate in an interview with him (in Spanish) that you can find on youtube. You can find relatively up-to-date information on each of these languages at Ethnologue https://www.ethnologue.com/country/CO/languages